# Filter and join tables dinamically using JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, filtering

This is my very first time posting something on here, so I will try to keep it breif.

I am looking for a way to get more information from my existing information by filtering and joining multiple tables in my mysql database using JPA repository and Springboot 2.7.3 in java 11.

As of now I am able to pick just 1 table and apply filters on it, I do it by using this (see below),
but just in the same table, I can not join it with an other table and extract more data

Is there any post or recommendation for me to do it?

By iterating a list of FilterTemplate objects and creating an Specification I can filter.

```java
public class FilterTemplate{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String attribute;         //"userName", "age", "creationDate"
    private String value;             //"0", "Jhon", "2023-11-02 23:52:18.561888"
    private String objectType;        //int, double, string, LocalDateTime, etc.
    private String verificationType;  //EQUAL, GT, LT, GET, LET, LIKE
}
```

(ignore @Id and @GeneratedValue, I used them to store those filter objects in my db)

What I am thinking is to be able to pick 1 upto 3 tables (could be more, 3 is what I am looking for), they inner joined themselfs and I start filtering on their fields.